# Find a distance in graphs between nodes

Tags: haskell, distance

I got a list in my hand such:

```
[(1,2),(1,4),(2,4),(3,9),(4,7),(7,9)]
```

I have to implement a function which takes: a **list of existing relations**, a **pair of new realiton**,a **distance n.**

Function should work in this way: It takes all parameters, calculates distance between nodes which is given in a new relation, if distance is <= to distance n, function returns the list including the new relationship.

For ex:

```
list = [(1,2),(1,4),(2,4),(3,9),(4,7),(7,9)]

new_relation = [(1,3)]

distance_n = 4
```

It will return [(1,2),**(1,3)**,(1,4),(2,4),(3,9),(4,7),(7,9)]

If distance was 3 it would return the original list

```
[(1,2),(1,4),(2,4),(3,9),(4,7),(7,9)]
```

How I can do this? I have a problems with graphs.
Note: It should be implemented in Haskell.

Comment: Step 1: [Learn more about graphs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics))

Answer (score 1):

As always in Haskell, we start by declaring our types.  Here' I'm just going to say that a `Graph` is a list of `Edge`s, and an `Edge` is a tuple of `Node`s, which are just `Int`s

```
type Node = Int
type Edge = (Int, Int)
type Graph = [Edge]
```

Then we can declare our functions' types.  First we have a function that solves the specific problem

```
addNode :: Graph -> Edge -> Int -> Graph
addNode graph newEdge maxDistance = undefined
```

But we know from the problem statement that we're going to need a helper, namely a function that calculates the distance between two nodes (which can be undefined if the nodes aren't connected).  Since this doesn't always have a valid value to return, we'll wrap it in `Maybe` and return `Nothing` when the nodes aren't connected

```
distance :: Graph -> Node -> Node -> Maybe Int
distance graph fromNode toNode = undefined
```

With this helper function, we can now implement `addNode` pretty simply

```
addNode graph newEdge@(fromNode, toNode) maxDistance =
    case distance graph fromNode toNode of
        Nothing -> graph
        Just d  ->
            if d <= maxDistance
                then newEdge : graph
                else graph
```

But it looks like you want to keep the graph sorted, so if you import `Data.List` you can just toss in `sort`

```
addNode graph newEdge@(fromNode, toNode) maxDistance =
    case distance graph fromNode toNode of
        Nothing -> graph
        Just d  ->
            if d <= maxDistance
                then sort $ newEdge : graph
                else graph
```

Now all you have to do is implement `distance` and you'll be done.

Answer (score 1):

Both [the containers package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) and [the graphs package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphs) have adjacency list representations that are similar to yours.

[A Very General Method of Computing Shortest Paths](http://r6.ca/blog/20110808T035622Z.html) contains a functional implementation of Djikstra's algorithm for finding graph distances, but it works on an adjacency matrix.  Either do a change of representation or alter the algorithm to work on adjacency lists.

Once you actually have a function distance :: Graph -> Vertex -> Vertex -> Distance, and a function addEdge :: Edge -> Graph -> Graph, you are golden.  addEdge should be relatively easy to write independent of representation, but in general adding an edge means you have to throw-away any previous, cached distance calculations.